# iterate through array elements using its own pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, while-loop

```
int* arr = new int[30](); //30 is random serving the example's purposes

while(<insert check here that uses the arr pointer>){

   cout<<*arr<<endl;

   arr++;
}
```

This is me experimenting on tricks using pointers and I have been working on this for some time today. I have used many different checks in the while clause without ever getting it right (mostly ending up with infinite loops or seg faults). **So my question can this be done or the standard for-loop method is the only way?**

Comment: Note that by incrementing `arr`, the only pointer you have to that memory allocation, you've lost the ability to `delete[]` it without an extreme amount of effort. Make a copy before you start incrementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to do this.

add

```
int *end = arr + 30;
while (arr < end)
```

Of course, by incrementing "arr", you are losing the pointer to the array - but you knew that already :-)

Comment: I thought when I increment arr I just move on to the next element of the array...why am I losing the pointer? And second your answer is nice but I try to do the check without using the size of the array just by checking the pointer alone

Comment: C++ doesn't track the size of the array - so you need to do this manually.

Comment: So there isn't something that indicates that the pointer reached the end of the array? Something similar like the null termination in strings.

Comment: "arr" is the pointer to the memory you allocated. "arr++" modifies this pointer - so now your program doesn't have a pointer to the start of the array anymore. Say "new" returns 0x1000. arr==0x1000. After the first time thru the loop, arr==0x1004 (assuming sizeof(int)==4). Now, you don't have the address of the start of the array anymore.

Comment: WRT array: Nope. "null terminated strings" is essentially a convention - place a zero at the end of the string. Note that sometimes programs will use strings with embedded zeros, so they need to keep track of overall string length in some other way.

Comment: Use std::vector<> instead of a raw array - now it will track it for you.

Comment: My logic is that after many "arr++" I reach an address that corresponds to the arr[29] content. If I do arr++ after I am there the content of the next address is random non sense?is it null?

Comment: It is undefined. Accessing arr[30] may give you a segfault (terminating the program), or may return the value 0, or some other random value. In fact, given "a=new int[10]; b=new int[10]", it is possible that "a[15]" references part of b - of course you cannot depend on this in any way. It may be instructive to add "printf("arr is %p\n", arr);" inside your loop, and just before the start of the loop.